# Vuetify Calendar -- Customizing default Head Day Label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify calendar for making appointments. I tried to customize the default header of the calendar using slots but not getting expected result.Wants to customize it like as shown in the image ... [image: I want to make the default header bar like this]
Code

```
<v-calendar ref="calendar" :now="today" :value="today" :events="events" color="primary" type="week">
        <template v-slot:day-header="{date}">
          <v-btn color="success">{{date}}</v-btn>
        </template>
```

Codepen for the same: `https://codepen.io/spider007/pen/YzyGgPY`

Comment: I think you have to use type `custom-weekly` and customize the entire day slot

Comment: You'd have to use hide-header

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute weekday-format with a custom function the input is the event and then you can return custom headings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).